# IsAuthentification set as false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a custom authorisation class which allows me to check the user if they are *Admin* and also if they have the correct user role to access some pages. For example if the user is an *Admin* they should be able to access all client pages, but if a user has only one type of client access rights then they will only go to that specifics clients page. However, this isn't working.

If I boot up a fresh version of my program in a new browser window `IsAuthenicated` will be set to false on the role extension. However, if I re run the program again in the same browser instance, it will then say that the user IS authenticated and would carry on like normal. Does anybody know how to fix the fact that the user is not set as authenticated on the first instance of the browser?

Login:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model); ;
            }
            if (returnUrl == null || returnUrl == "/")
            {
                returnUrl = "/APL/HomePage/Index";
            }
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Homepage", new { client = User.Role() });
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

Custom Authorization class:

```
public class AuthorizeClient : AuthorizeAttribute {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
            bool rt = false;
            if (httpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin")) {
            string clientName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["client"].ToString();
            rt = false;
        }
         else if (httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["client"] != null) {
            string clientName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["client"].ToString();
            rt = httpContext.User.IsInRole(clientName);
        }


            return rt;
        }
```

Role Extension:

```
public static string Role(this IPrincipal user) {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims) {
                    if (claim.Type == "Role")
                        return claim.Value;
                }
                return "";
            }
            else
                return "";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated won't be set to true until the next request after calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie().

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(acct.UserName, true); after validating user and make sure you set  in web.config

The SetAuthCookie method adds a forms-authentication ticket to either the cookies collection, or to the URL if CookiesSupported is false. The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication information to the next request made by the browser.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx